# PR2 sensing question

Tags: ros, tabletop-object-detector, pr2-tabletop-manipulation-apps, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,
I am using Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04 and have some trouble figuring out how to implement color sensing on my code.

I want PR2 to distinguish a red block and a blue block but I can't find any relative code in the libraries. I found out that in the pick_and_place_manager.py, there is a call_tabletop_detection, which detects graspable objects by numbering them starting from zero relative to the distance of the block from the edge of the table.

Can anyone help me how I can make PR2 distinguish red block and blue block by any method?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38764/pr2-sensing-question/) by [joey0702](https://answers.ros.org/users/2681/joey0702/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The graspable objects in the pick_and_place_manager contain the point clusters, which have RGB information.  These webpages will hopefully make it clear how to access that information:
https://kforge.ros.org/Sushi/trac/wiki/Perception/PointCloud2InPython
https://kforge.ros.org/Sushi/trac/wiki/Perception/PointCloud2MessageStructure

if you just take the average r and b values for the points in each object, you should be able to tell red from blue.

---

Originally posted by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) with karma: 741 on 2013-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0